# Displaying Sender View From Intranet Web Site

Tags: docusignapi

We are trying to display the sender view via embedded signing in a http based intranet web application. But DocuSign is returning an https based URL for sender view & when we are trying to display it in iframe we are getting a session timeout window in DocuSign.

We cannot host the intranet site in https.
Any work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of embedding DocuSign an iFrame, launch the DocuSign URL in a new window/tab.  Doing so (i.e., using a new window/tab -- NOT an iFrame) is actually best practice for a number of reasons, including:

- iFrames do not typically provide a good user experience on mobile devices
- some types of browsers have issues with displaying DocuSign within an
  iFrame (do to security restrictions that are typically enforced by
  browsers for third-party apps operating within an iFrame)

The DocuSign API documentation actually recommends against using iFrames, specifically within any app that will be accessed via mobile device.

Comment: We are having an intranet site mainly for internal operations which will not be viewed in mobile devices. Also if we open the DocuSign window in another tab user will have to switch between Tabs. We have to display the Embedded DocuSign console within the Application Page itself.